# Can I have a one table row with cells on each side of the page?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm designing a website right now, and have a menubar at the top for navigation. It is all done as one table and CSS. This works well in all browsers, however, I want to have the navigation buttons on the left, and the login and home buttons on the right.

I can easily do this by putting the right hand buttons in their own div, and using the position: fixed element to position it. However, as I'm sure you all know, this does not work with Internet Explorer. Since my div method is a work around of sorts to begin with, I do not want to add another work around to my work around just for IE.

So I began to wonder if there was a way to keep the entire menu bar in one table row instead of two, but have the cells for the right hand buttons aligned to the right, and the cells for the left hand buttons on the left. I figure that would be much neater than my div work around, and it would work with IE. I have no idea if it is even possible though, and I can't find anything on it. Any help would be appreciated, even if it's a different method then what I suggested.

Comment: if you post some sample markup/css it would be very helpful.

Comment: i can't help but wonder why you are using a table to do this? is there some reason why the standard method of block elements can't be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really simple fix for you. If you know how to put your CSS in a separate file do that, otherwise you can put it in your head section.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Nav 1</td>
    <td>Nav 2</td>
    <td>Nav 3</td>
    <td class="right">Login</td>
    <td class="right">Home</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}
```

The search engines don't like it so much but you can also post it inline like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Nav 1</td>
    <td>Nav 2</td>
    <td>Nav 3</td>
    <td style="float:right">Login</td>
    <td style="float:right">Home</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Even though I did not end up using this method, I think I will apply it once I have the time and motivation to go in and edit the menu again. Thank's for the clever solution though, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `position: fixed` keeps the post at this position in the browser window whether you scroll up or down, are you sure that's the behavior you're looking for?

As for your problem: You should make one bigger div to surround the two smaller ones and position it on top of the page. Here's an example:

```
<div id="top-bar">
<div id="rightbuttons">Three | Four</div>
<div id="leftbuttons">One | Two</div>
</div>
```

For this example, I'll position the entire bar on top:

```
#top-bar { position: absolute; width: 100%; left:0; right:0; }
```

And then, to position the inside bars, I'll use a `float` property: this property lets the element "float" in either position.

```
#rightbuttons { float: right; }
#leftbuttons { float: left; }
```

Then as a "hack" to make sure the floating divs still make the outside div keep the height according to its content, we add `overflow:hidden` to it

```
#top-bar { position: absolute; width: 100%; left:0; right:0; verflow: hidden; }
```

## [Here is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/OhMrBigshot/v6S75/).

Comment: This is what I had originally and ended up doing after all.  I was just hoping there was a neater way so IE compatibility would not be such a pain. I found a nice js script that forces it to apply CSS elements that work in good browsers, so that made this easier. I was mostly just curious.